# Mario CS50 in Python

Tags: python, cs50

so I tried coding the mario assignment from CS50 in python instead of C to challenge myself and I managed to get it to work! I don't quite understand how the loops are working, especially the math because I just played around to get the result I wanted.

The requirements of the assignment were as follows

1. Create a half pyramid using hashes
2. Make sure it's right aligned
3. It should correspond to the height given by the User
4. The first line should start with 2"#"s

Any clarification on my loops would be greatly appreciated :)

```
print('Height: ', end='');
h = int(input());

while(h<0 or h > 24):
  print("That is an invalid input")
  print('Height: ', end='');
  h = int(input());

for i in range(h):
    print(" "*(h-i)+"#"*(i+1));
```

Comment: That's not how the pyramid should print... That's only half the pyramid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, just wanted to point out, your code does not print out the entire pyramid; it only prints half of it out. Your output should something like (if we input height to be 3, for example):

```
  # #
 ## ##
### ###
```

Your code only prints the left side:

```
  #
 ##
###
```

Now, to your question. Here is how you got it to work:

> ```
> for i in range(h):
>      print(" " * (h - i) + "#" * (i + 1));
> ```

To describe the conditional statement of the for-loop, `i` starts at 0, and it goes up till `h`.

To understand how your `print()` statement works, think of it as a line segment that consists of spaces and hashes. The length of this segment is `h`. So, in `h - i`, you print part of this "segment" as spaces, and in `i + 1`, you print the remainder of the loop.

Now, the reason you use `i + 1`, and not just `i` is because of the for-loop condition; `i` starts at zero. As a result, you must have realized that the first line has no hashes, as there is `h - 0` spaces, and `0` hashes. That is why the `i + 1` was required; you are printing an extra space at the start of every line, if you check closely with your current code.

A more easier-to-understand logic of your code, with the same results, is:

```
for i in range(1, h + 1): # The counter's range is toyed with here
    print(" " * (h - i) + "#" * i); # The "i + 1" is removed
```

Here, the range of the loop is toyed with; now it starts at 1 (so that the first hash is printed, and the entire "segment" is not only spaces in the first line), and it ends at `h + 1` (so that the range of the loop stays the same).

The `i + 1` is removed; seeing the `print()` statement makes it easier to understand the "segment" logic discussed above.

**Just to clarify, the alternate code I provided above is not intended as a replacement to your code; I just included it to reinforce my "segment" idea. Your code is perfectly fine and works just as well as mine.*

Answer (score 1):

### range(start, stop[, step])

Python range() function returns a list of integers from some lower bound (zero, by default) up to (but not including) some upper bound, possibly in increments (steps) of some other number (one, by default).
Hence,

```
range(3) returns a sequence: 0, 1, 2
range(1,3) returns a sequence: 1, 2
range(1,7,2) returns a sequence: 1, 3, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

i think, it isn't right answer. For understanding it, use `"_"` or other symbols instead spaces. If `height = 1`, we can see `_#`, but must be `#`. So right answer, can be:

```
print('Height: ', end='');
h = int(input());

while(h<0 or h > 24):
  print("That is an invalid input")
  print('Height: ', end='');
  h = int(input());

for i in range(h):
     print("_" * (h - (i+1)) + "#" * (i + 1));
```

sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

**You'd want to break them up into two so you can see the picture clearly.From there the side by side implementation will be easier.**

```
left_align_counter =  0
print("Printing  left aligned")
print("Height: ", end="")
height =  int(input())

for h in range(height):
    left_align_counter +=1 
    print("#"*left_align_counter)

print("DONE.")

right_align_counter = 0
print("Printing right align ")

for h in range(height):
    right_align_counter += 1
    print(" "*int(height-right_align_counter), end="")
    print("#"*int(right_align_counter))
    
print("DONE.")
```

***Printing side by side***

```
left_align_counter =  0
print("Printing  left aligned")
print("Height: ", end="")
height =  int(input())

for h in range(height):
    left_align_counter +=1 
    print("#"*left_align_counter)

print("DONE.")

right_align_counter = 0
print("Printing right align ")

for h in range(height):
    right_align_counter += 1
    print(" "*int(height-right_align_counter), end="")
    print("#"*int(right_align_counter))
    
print("DONE.")

#here we can use any counter for the blocks be it right or left so just use counter variable
counter = 0
for h in range(height):
    counter += 1
    print(" "*int(height-counter), end="")
    print("#"*int(counter), end=' ')
    print("#"*int(counter),end="\n")
```